# Exchange authorizational code works only once - Oauth2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to implement this code. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials#retrieve_oauth_20_credentials

I have my client id and client_secrets json for webapps, because I'm extracting some values from a spreadsheet, everything is ok and I already have spreadsheet's data in my application. But my question is How can I make to re-use that authorization code multiple times?, because I have to extract more data from that spreadsheet, my URL is http://localhost:8080/cluster/?state=/profile&code=xxxxxxx but for example when I try to refresh that page this error appears.

An error occurred: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed."
}

I have the same implementation of the url, but the only difference is I changed this methods storeCredentials(userId, credentials) - getStoredCredentials(userId) and put that values into a db table.

So, How can I implement 'exchange authorization code'? and how can I link my application to the new url?

Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

First at all, following the protocol the authorization code MUST BE used once, so the auth server must invalidate it after the first use.

If you want to use it for another part of your implementation, you can save it, use it and send a 302 redirect to your other page witch use your getStoredCredentials method

Comment: For the moment I don't need a redirect, because I need to extract the same information for the same page like 'refresh page' but if I do that I got a 'Code was already redeemed'. I already stored the userId, accessToken and refreshToken, but I don't know how to use it to re-send it to exchangeCode method. :\